# Comment xml segment using shell script / command

Tags: bash, shell, sed, xml, editing

I am trying to do a shell script with 2 parameters.

```
xmlcomment -c cholo
```

or

```
xmlcomment -u cholo
```

Given the following xml file,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<guyList>
  <guy>
    <name>paco</name>
    <fullname>Paco Tilla</fullname>
    <theme>paco</theme>
  </guy>
  <guy>
    <name>cholo</name>
    <fullname>Cholo Cote</fullname>
    <theme>cholocote</theme>
  </guy>
  <guy>
    <name>temo</name>
    <fullname>Temo Lesto</fullname>
    <theme>temol</theme>
  </guy>
</guyList>
```

The first comments out the block "<guy>" that contains a "<name>paco</name>" , resulting in the following file change.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<guyList>
<guy>
    <name>paco</name>
    <fullname>Paco Tilla</fullname>
    <theme>paco</theme>
  </guy>
<!--
  <guy>
    <name>cholo</name>
    <fullname>Cholo Cote</fullname>
    <theme>cholocote</theme>
  </guy>
-->
  <guy>
    <name>temo</name>
    <fullname>Temo Lesto</fullname>
    <theme>temol</theme>
  </guy>
</guyList>
```

The second example just uncomments that same block (if commented) like presented in the first XML.

Any Idea on a good approach to do this? sed? some other XML editor?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use an XSLT processor for this, like `xsltproc`:

```
<xsl:template match="guy[name='cholo']">
  <xsl:comment>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
  </xsl:comment>
</xsl:template>
```

This approach does not fully reproduce the original XML structure, but it comments out the appropriate `guy` section.

The output is:

```
<guyList>
    <guy>
        <name>paco</name>
        <fullname>Paco Tilla</fullname>
        <theme>paco</theme>
    </guy>
    <!--
      cholo
      Cholo Cote
      cholocote
    -->
    <guy>
        <name>temo</name>
        <fullname>Temo Lesto</fullname>
        <theme>temol</theme>
    </guy>
</guyList>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this option will be kind of destructive for the file to go back in an uncomment operation as I stated in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done with `sed` (maybe not the best approach). The scripts are the same, just replacing line addresses and what substitute in each case.

```
sed '/<guy>/ {
    :a
    N
    /<\/guy>/ {
            /cholo/ {
                    s/^/<!--\n/
                    s/$/\n-->/
            }
    p
    d
    }
    ba
}' file-without-comment
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<guyList>
<guy>
    <name>paco</name>
    <fullname>Paco Tilla</fullname>
    <theme>paco</theme>
  </guy>
<!--
  <guy>
    <name>cholo</name>
    <fullname>Cholo Cote</fullname>
    <theme>cholocote</theme>
  </guy>
-->
  <guy>
    <name>temo</name>
    <fullname>Temo Lesto</fullname>
    <theme>temol</theme>
  </guy>
</guyList>

sed '/<!--/ {
    :a
    N
    /-->/ {
            /cholo/ {
                    s/<!--\n//
                    s/\n-->//
            }
    p
    d
    }
    ba
}' file-with-comment                                          
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<guyList>
<guy>
    <name>paco</name>
    <fullname>Paco Tilla</fullname>
    <theme>paco</theme>
  </guy>
  <guy>
    <name>cholo</name>
    <fullname>Cholo Cote</fullname>
    <theme>cholocote</theme>
  </guy>
  <guy>
    <name>temo</name>
    <fullname>Temo Lesto</fullname>
    <theme>temol</theme>
  </guy>
</guyList>
```

EDIT 23/mar/2020

The script above works with GNUsed.
In BSD sed (and Mac sed?) it works with a escaped literal new line.

```
sed '/<guy>/ {
    :a
    N
    /<\/guy>/ {
            /cholo/ {
                    s/^/<!--\
/
                    s/$/\
-->/
            }
    p
    d
    }
    ba
}' file-without-comment
```

But it doesn't work with the "uncomment" script, I don't know why.
I can be done with this sed script:

```
sed -E '/<!--|-->/d' file-with-comment
```

Comment: Hi.
It´s not working for me on my Mac. I am getting this:
`<?xml version=1.0?>
<guyList>
  <guy>
    <name>paco</name>
    <fullname>Paco Tilla</fullname>
    <theme>paco</theme>
  </guy>
<!--n  <guy>
    <name>cholo</name>
    <fullname>Cholo Cote</fullname>
    <theme>cholocote</theme>
  </guy>n-->
  <guy>
    <name>temo</name>
    <fullname>Temo Lesto</fullname>
    <theme>temol</theme>
  </guy>
</guyList>`

Comment: I edited my answer. That was due to compatibility between GNU sed and BSD sed. I don't know if it will work in Mac sed.